# GRPC Failed using geocoder

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm using android studio.

I'm trying to get location name from googlemaps when clicked.

I'm using geocoder.

Everytime i click somewhere on the map , marker goes there but i cant get the city name and i get a grpc failed error.

What should i do ?I tried this with **api 23,24,25** none of them worked.

My onMapClick function :

```
 @Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Konum"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this.getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());

    try {
        List<Address> city = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude,1);
        if (city != null && city.size() > 0){
            Log.i("Info",city.get(0).getLocality());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: grpc failed
>   W/System.err:     at com.example.umut.googlemapstest.MapsActivity$override.onMapClick(MapsActivity.java:127)

Which shows

```
List<Address> city = geocoder.getFromLocation(latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude,1);
```

This code

Comment: Is this on an emulator or an actual device? There's a known problem with the Geocoder not working on the Android emulator.

Comment: Yeap i'm using android studio emulator.I dont have an actual android device.Is there any alternatives ?

Comment: There currently isn't any workaround for emulators unfortunately.

Comment: Any luck with you? I have this issue in motorola device and it is working well with me on emulator.

Comment: I believe the problem with it not working on emulator should be fixed now.

Comment: I also have this issue on a specific Moto device. Works well on another device same model

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for exception "java.io.ioexception grpc failed":

```java
try {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
    List addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); 
    List<Address> addresslist = addresses;
    String address = addresslist.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
    Log.d("add",address);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```